# Own metrics on Rsocket Proxy for Prometheus in Spring Cloud Data Flow Tasks

Tags: prometheus, spring-cloud-dataflow, rsocket

I'm trying to establish a monitoring for *short living Spring Cloud Data Flow tasks*. Since newer versions of SCDF, it is recommended to use the *[rsocket proxy for prometheus](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/prometheus-rsocket-proxy)*.

Based on the helm chart, I was able to deploy the rsocket proxy. Connectivity is working and the proxy's own metrics are available in prometheus. But I'm still struggling to expose own meter during the application.

I included the required dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>prometheus-rsocket-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <-- Next two: required or not? -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>prometheus-rsocket-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rsocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>rsocket-transport-netty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

And in the application, I added a simple counter to the code:

```
   private PrometheusMeterRegistry meterRegistry = new PrometheusMeterRegistry(PrometheusConfig.DEFAULT);
   private PrometheusRSocketClient client;

   private Counter                 reqCounter;

   @PostConstruct
   public void initMontitor() {
        client = PrometheusRSocketClient.build(meterRegistry, TcpClientTransport.create("scdf-dev-prometheus-proxy.batch-dev", 7001))
                .connect();
        reqCounter = meterRegistry.counter("batch.example.count", "client", "example");   
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void releaseMontitor() {   
        client.pushAndClose();
    }

    @Override
    public Result process(Usage usage) {
        reqCounter.increment();
        /// ...
   }
```

The application run without any problems. But no metrics are visible, nether on prometheus itself, nor on the /metrics/connected endpoint of the proxy. What's missing?

EDIT:
Ok, meanwhile I found out, that the communication between the my task and RSocket Proxy is working. But in opposite to the [documentation](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/prometheus-rsocket-proxy#support-for-short-lived-or-serverless-applications) "... will hold them [the metrics] until the next scrape by Prometheus", my metric at the 'metrics/connected' endpoint are gone as soon as my application ends.

Comment: Oliver, looks like this is a regression in the latest micrometer/prometheus-proxy library.

I've reported the issue and working with the micrometer team to understand what is going on: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/prometheus-rsocket-proxy/issues/35

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get my custom spring cloud dataflow task to expose actuators to prometheus by setting the following...

Add these dependencies to your pom or build.gradle

1. implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
2. implementation group: 'io.micrometer.prometheus', name: 'prometheus-rsocket-spring', version: '1.3.0'

Add the following to your application.yml

```
management:
  security:
    enabled: false
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: info,prometheus,metrics
  endpoint:
    info:
      enabled: true
```